# How do I split a String into 2-4 long blocks?

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a string of numbers (e.g. 2005002193401) into blocks of a maximum length of 4. So I did the following:

```
String numbers = "2005002193401";
while (numbers.length() > 4) {
  System.out.print(numbers.substring(0, 4) + " ");
  numbers = numbers.substring(4);
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

That gives me the following: **2005 0021 9340 1**

Now here's my problem. The blocks should have atleast a length of 2 (and a maximum of 4), and should preferably not start with a 0. 
So more like this: **200 500 219 3401** or this **200 500 2193 401**

I already looked around a bit, but couldn't find a real solution to anything...

Does anyone know an easy way to do it?

Comment: This may not always be possible though - what if the caller passes in a string like `30000000000000`?

Comment: That's why I said preferably, if it's not possible it doesn't have to be. The main focus is that the blocks shouldn't be shorter than 2 and longer than 4 numbers.

Comment: In this case, you can use the simple rule: say the string is `9999123456`, you can: 1) take chunks of four chars greedily until you have <8 characters left (in this example `9999`, `123456`); 2) If the remaining string also has four chars, you can decide to keep it as is, or split it into two `2-char` strings; 2) otherwise, you can get more creative in terms of how you want to split the remainder (in this example, `12 3456`, `123 456`, or `1234 56`).

Comment: @Zz'Rot This method does not work under the "can't start with 0" constraint. You can definitely deal with numbers like 12340123 by checking for the 0. But, consider for example 1111 11000111. After the initial four digits get taken. It's impossible to split the remaining eight with the greedy method. Though 111 11 1000 111 works. If you add checks complicated enough to deal with situations like this you will probably end up with something as complex as my brutal solution.

Comment: take a look at my solution, remember that the hardest can be sometimes solved easly using regex

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task. Here is the solution in Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(trickySplit("2005002193401")?.joinToString("-"))
}

fun trickySplit(s: String): LinkedList<String>? {
    if (s.isEmpty()) return LinkedList()

    return s.splitUsing(headSize = 4) ?: 
           s.splitUsing(headSize = 3) ?: 
           s.splitUsing(headSize = 2)
}

fun String.splitUsing(headSize: Int): LinkedList<String>? {
    return toHeadAndTail(headSize)
            ?.takeUnless { it.second.startsWith("0") }
            ?.let { it.first addToList trickySplit(it.second) }
}

fun String.toHeadAndTail(headSize: Int): Pair<String, String>? {
    return if (length >= headSize) take(headSize) to drop(headSize) else null
}

infix fun String.addToList(list: LinkedList<String>?): LinkedList<String>? {
    list?.push(this)
    return list;
}
```

Output: `200-5002-193-401`

And translation to Java is slightly more verbose:

```
public class TrickySplitter {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new TrickySplitter().trickySplit("2005002193401")
                            .map(it -> String.join("-", it))
                            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    public Optional<LinkedList<String>> trickySplit(String s) {
        if (s.isEmpty()) return Optional.of(new LinkedList<>());

        return splitUsing(s, 4)
                .or(() -> splitUsing(s, 3))
                .or(() -> splitUsing(s, 2));

    }

    private Optional<LinkedList<String>> splitUsing(String s, Integer headSize) {
        return toHeadAndTail(s, headSize)
                .filter(headAndTail -> !headAndTail[1].startsWith("0"))
                .map(headNTail -> addToList(headNTail[0], trickySplit(headNTail[1]).orElse(null)));

    }

    private Optional<String[]> toHeadAndTail(String s, Integer headSize) {
        if (s.length() >= headSize) {
            return Optional.of(new String[]{s.substring(0, headSize), s.substring(headSize, s.length())});
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private LinkedList<String> addToList(String s, LinkedList<String> list) {
        if (list != null) list.push(s);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Java solution is as follows. Admittedly it's not a smart method since it brutally goes through every possibility and adds those that are valid into solutions. But it works. If you can't understand I can add comments.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> solutions;

private static void dfs(List<Integer> nextIndexes[], Stack<Integer> currentRecord, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == nextIndexes.length) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(currentRecord);
        solutions.add(result);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = nextIndexes[currentIndex].size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int endingIndex = nextIndexes[currentIndex].get(i);
        currentRecord.push(endingIndex);
        dfs(nextIndexes, currentRecord, endingIndex + 1);
        currentRecord.pop();
    }
}

public static void generateSolutions(String number) {
    ArrayList<Integer> nextIndexes[] = new ArrayList[number.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        nextIndexes[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        if (number.charAt(i) == '0') {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = 1; i + j < number.length() && j <= 3; j++) {
            nextIndexes[i].add(i + j);
        }
    }
    Stack<Integer> currentRecord = new Stack<>();
    solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    dfs(nextIndexes, currentRecord, 0);
}

public static void splitNumbers(String number) {
    generateSolutions(number);
    for (List<Integer> solution: solutions) {
        int beginIndex = -1;
        String answer = "";
        for (int index: solution) {
            answer += number.substring(beginIndex + 1, index + 1) + " ";
            beginIndex = index;
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    splitNumbers("10234056708208");
}
```

Results for "10234056708208" are:

```
1023 4056 708 208 

1023 4056 70 8208 

1023 405 6708 208 

1023 405 670 8208 

1023 40 5670 8208 

1023 40 56 708 208 

1023 40 56 70 8208 

102 3405 6708 208 

102 3405 670 8208 

102 340 5670 8208 

102 340 56 708 208 

102 340 56 70 8208 

10 2340 5670 8208 

10 2340 56 708 208 

10 2340 56 70 8208 

10 23 4056 708 208 

10 23 4056 70 8208 

10 23 405 6708 208 

10 23 405 670 8208 

10 23 40 5670 8208 

10 23 40 56 708 208 

10 23 40 56 70 8208
```

Answer (score 1):

What comes in my mind is that you can divide the length of numbers with 2 or 3. this will give you number of parts with 2 or 3 elements. Then get the rest of division of numbers/parts. While the rest of latest division is greater than 0 add one element to 1st part, and move on. Here is some code:

```
int n = numbers.length();
int parts = n/3;
int leftover = n%parts;
int next = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n - n/parts;) {
     i = next;
     if (leftover > 0) {
         leftover--;
         next+=n/parts + 1;
     } else {
         next+=n/parts;
     }
     System.out.print(numbers.substring(i, next) + ", ");
}
```

For your input:

> 2005002193401

will give

> 2005, 002, 193, 401

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler solution using regex with split

```
String word = "1234efgh5678ij";
String[] split = word.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split));
```

we are using a [boundary match](https://jrebel.com/wp-content/uploads/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet.pdf) to tell him to split in every 4th character ( G for the end, 4 mean the fourth, the `.` I don't care what charcter it is "any") here split in the end if there is no more it will return the last remaining characters